# Python Django - automatic log out - inactive user

Tags: python, django

i want to automatic log out my application when  user does not do anything .
first user login then user is not active 30 mint. after 30 mint , need to log out automatically

how can i done it from client side using python- Django

i tried Django-session-time out   , using this.

https://pypi.org/project/django-session-timeout/

. but its not working in client side.

client side always active mode.. how can i log out the inactive user ?

Answer (score 0):

No need of 3rd party package. Add [SESSION_COOKIE_AGE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) in your settings.py.

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1800
```